# why my query is not working. i wrote a query for identifying number of absent and number of present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select [First Name],[Last Name],Class,
(
    select count([Date]) from Attendence where [Roll Number] ='1' and [Student Status] ='P' 
) as [No Of Present],
(
    select count([Date]) from Attendence where [Roll Number] ='1' and [Student Status] ='A'
)as [No Of Absent]
from Attendence
where [Date] between '2018-09-1' and '2018-09-30'
```

This is a I wrote for my software but it is not giving the right outcome. I want to calculate amount of present and absent for students.

Comment: _" it is not giving the right outcome"_ what would be the _right_ outcome? In what way the current is different?

Comment: You could improve your data model. The student should be stored in it's own table and not in the `Attendance` table. Then link the `Student` and `Attendance` tables via foreign-key. Otherwise you have to repeat it's names for every attendance and you can't have a student without attendance.

Answer (score 1):

use conditional aggregation:

```
select [First Name],[Last Name],Class from
count(case [Student Status] ='P' then 1 end) as [No Of Present], 
count(case [Student Status] ='A'  then 1 end)as [No Of Absent] 
from Attendence where [Date] between '2018-09-1' and '2018-09-30' and [Roll Number] ='1'
group by [First Name],[Last Name],Class
```

Comment: Even if this would be the solution i don't like answers that are posted before the question is clear. Otherwise people don't learn that it's important to explain the issue. The question is also not helpful for any future reader.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I fully agree with u , next time I'll follow your suggestion definitely

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is different from outer query, it should be correlated :

But, you can do in single `select` statement with `case` expression instead of two subquery :

```
select [First Name], [Last Name], Class, 
       sum(case when [Student Status] = 'P' then 1 else 0 end) as [No Of Present], 
       sum(case when [Student Status] = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as [No Of Absent] 
from Attendence at
where [Date] between '2018-09-1' and '2018-09-30' and [Roll Number] = '1'
group by [First Name], [Last Name], Class;
```

Comment: Thank-you for answer :) but when i execute query it shows this error     Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: @user10379355. . . You missed `when` in `case` expression.

Comment: And now it worked. When was missing. Thank-you all for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your query might work, but you forgot to use distinct. Please find the below rectified query :

```
select distinct [First Name],[Last Name],Class,
(
select count([Date]) from Attendence where [Roll Number] ='1' and [Student Status] ='P' 
) as [No Of Present],
(
select count([Date]) from Attendence where [Roll Number] ='1' and [Student Status] ='A'
)as [No Of Absent]
from Attendence
where [Date] between '2018-09-1' and '2018-09-30'
group by [First Name],[Last Name],Class
```